# Get a method from the same object

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = {
    this.bar = function(){},
    this.baz = new this.bar()
}
```

This won't work. I want `foo.baz` to be a `foo.baz`. How do I do it?

Comment: What is a `foo.baz`?  There is no definition of that type of object and you can't make one without a definition for one.  There's no constructor for it.  There's no prototype for it.  As you've worded your question, it really doesn't make any sense.  Perhaps you could describe better what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `foo` is an object just fine.  You just can't use `this` in the definition of a literal and expect it to be the current object.  Javascript just doesn't work that way.  `this` is set by the JS interpreter for function calls and constructor calls - that's it.

Answer (score 1):

foo is an object literal, not an instance, so you can't use the "this" keyword in it (or semicolons, etc.)

Change your code to:

```
var foo = function() {
    this.bar = function(){},
    this.baz = new this.bar()
}

new foo();
```

Or:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {}
}

foo.baz = new foo.bar()
```

Comment: Your terminology is not really correct.  `foo` is an instance of an Object.  You can't use `this` in the definition of a literal simply because Javascript does not allow you do do that.  `this` is only set by the interpreter for a function call and defining a literal is not a function call.

Comment: "An object literal is a comma-separated list of name-value pairs wrapped in curly braces." It is also an instance of object. Syntacticly, neither "this" nor the use of semicolons is correct.